# How to prove the upper bound of $\int\limits_{2}^n \dfrac{1}{\log_2 x}dx$ is $\dfrac{n}{\log_2 n} $?

Tags: integration

I've been trying to prove that the upper bound of $$\int\limits_{2}^n \dfrac{1}{\log_2 x}dx$$ is $\dfrac{n}{\log_2 n}$ with integration by part since it is not an elementary function, but of no use, can anyone tell me how or is there any other easier way to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: lg is natural log?

Comment: @xyz base 2 log, but I  don't know how to type that, sorry

Comment: $dx$ is missing in the integral

Comment: the integral diverges to $+\infty$

Comment: @Masacroso Ok now I change the range to 2-n, consider n a constant not infinity, so it must be bounded by some function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you wrote is the lower bound.

$$\int\limits_{2}^n \dfrac{dx}{\log_2 (x)}dx=\log(2)\int\limits_{2}^n \dfrac{dx}{\log( x)}dx=\log(2)\Big[\text{li}(n)-\text{li}(2) \Big]$$

The full asymptotics of the  logarithmic integral function is

$$ \operatorname{li}(n) \sim \frac{n}{\log(n)} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k!}{[\log(n)]^k}$$
$$ \operatorname{li}(n) \sim \frac{n}{\log
   (n)}+\frac{n}{\log ^2(n)}+\frac{2 n}{\log ^3(n)}+\frac{6 n}{\log ^4(n)}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is $(\operatorname{li}(n) - \operatorname{li}(2)) \cdot \log 2$, where $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is the logarithmic integral, defined by the Cauchy principal value
$$
\operatorname{li}(x)= \mathrm{PV}\int_0^t {\frac{{dt}}{{\log t}}} ,
$$
for $x>0$. Using its relation to the exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$ and the known error bound for the asymptotic expansion of the latter function (http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.E2), we have
$$\tag{1}
\operatorname{li}(x) = \frac{x}{{\log x}}\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{n!}}{{\log ^n x}}}  + R_N (x)} \right)
$$
where
$$\tag{2}
\left| {R_N (x)} \right| \le (\chi (N + 1) + 1)\frac{{N!}}{{\log ^N x}}
$$
for any non-negative integer $N$ and $x>1$ (empty sums are interpreted as zero). Here
$$
\chi (p) = \sqrt \pi  \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{p}{2} + 1} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{p}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}} < \sqrt {\frac{{\pi (p + 1)}}{2}} 
$$
for any $p>0$. Thus, in particular,
$$
\int_2^n {\frac{{dt}}{{\log _2 t}}}  < \operatorname{li}(n)\log 2 < \frac{n}{{\log _2 n}}\left( {1 + \left( {\sqrt {\frac{{3\pi }}{2}}  + 1} \right)\frac{1}{{\log n}}} \right) < \frac{n}{{\log _2 n}}\left( {1 + \frac{{3.2}}{{\log n}}} \right)
$$
for all $n\geq 2$. It is also clear from (1) and (2) that $n/\log_2 n$ cannot be an upper bound (at least for sufficiently large values of $n$).